# Enable "show_touches" via appium or adb on android emulator

Tags: android-emulator, adb, appium

Is it possible to enable the "show_touches" options on android from appium? Or via adb?

I have a appium test-script, which misbehaves. I have no Idea why, and I want to see  where exactly it clicks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
adb shell settings put system show_touches 1
```

Comment: if this was "obvious" you wouldn't need to answer it on stackoverflow

Comment: you can also use: `adb shell settings put system pointer_location 1` in order to enable the fancier touch & swipe monitor that shows coordinates, pressure and more